# How to run Mocha tests written in tsx?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, tsx

Is there any way to run `mocha` tests written in `typescript - tsx` ?

When I run

```
mocha --require ts-node/register sometest.tsx
```

or

```
mocha --require ts-node/register --compiler ts:ts-node/register --compiler tsx:ts-node/register sometest.tsx
```

And the error shows:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided. (17004)
```

By the way, is it possible to debug the tests written in `tsx` with WebStorm?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was making sure my `.tsconfig` is configured with:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My packages:

```
"mocha": "6.2.2",
"ts-node": "8.5.0",
```

I think the `--compiler` flag for Mocha is deprecated as of today. In IntelliJ IDEA (should be very similar in WebStorm) I have adjusted the settings for Mocha tests so that I could run them in the IDE by opening **Run/Debug Configurations** (top right corner) and editing the **Templates** for *Mocha*.

The extra options are `-r ts-node/register`
[image: IntelliJ IDEA Mocha tests configuration]

My `package.json` test script:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha -r ts-node/register --ui bdd './src/**/*.spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'",
```

Also try to change the *Mocha* package from global to local (in your *node_modules*). The debugging worked for me as well.